# How can I add an item to a struct member that is an `Option<Vec<...>>`?

Tags: rust

How can I add an item to a struct member that is an `Option<Vec<...>>`?

In other words, what do I need to to to make `add_foo` below work?

```rust
struct Foo {
    value: u32,
}

struct Bar {
    foos: Option<Vec<Foo>>, 
}

impl Bar {
    fn add_foo(&mut self, foo: Foo) {
        if self.foos.is_none() {
            self.foos = Some(vec![]);
        }
        self.foos.unwrap().push(foo);
//      ^^^^^^^^^ move occurs because `self.foos` has type `Option<Vec<Foo>>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait        
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut bar = Bar{foos: None};
    bar.add_foo(Foo{value:42});
}
```

The error message suggests adding `as_ref()` but that doesn't help:

```
        self.foos.as_ref().unwrap().push(foo);
//      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot borrow as mutable
```

I though there might be something as `as_mutref()` but there is no such thing. Since I already hold a mutable reference to the `Bar` struct, I would expect to be able to change the `foos` field in the `Bar` struct.

Apologies if my terminology is off; still getting used to the whole Rust ownership concept.

Comment: There is `AsMut::as_mut`, which is the `mut` equivalent of `AsRef::as_ref`, haven't read the question thoroughly so not sure how helpful it will be though

Comment: @cameron1024  Thanks! Yes, that solved it. Despite quite a bit of Googling,`as_mut` never came up. If you post this as a solution rather than a comment, I will mark it as the accepted solution.

Comment: Unless you need to distinguish between `None` and an empty vector (`Some(vec![])`), you should just use `Vec<Foo>` instead of `Option<Vec<Foo>>`. `vec![]` doesn't allocate any memory up front, so an empty vector isn't more costly than `None`.

Comment: @FrancisGagné It really needs to be Option<Vec<...>> because I am using `serde_yaml` to de-serialize a YAML file, and it wants the`Opt` to be there because the keyword is optional (to distinguish between an absent list and an empty lists)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like the following might be what you're looking for:

```rust
fn add_foo(&mut self, foo: Foo) {
  if let Some(foos) = self.foos.as_mut() {
    // foos has type: &mut Vec<Foo>
    foos.push(foo);
  } else {
    self.foos = Some(vec![foo]);
  }
}
```

In general, using an `if let` or `match` or some other destructuring syntax is considered more idiomatic than using a `is_some()` check followed by an `unwrap()`. At the very least it saves on a comparison, but more importantly is harder to make accidentally panic.

Comment: Eventually, one can simply say `self.foos.get_or_insert_default().push(foo);`.

Comment: And in the meantime, until that function is stabilized, `self.foos.get_or_insert(vec![]).push(...);` works too